# How to dynamically use an interface?

Tags: angular

I'm writing up an SDK and I'm using a method callApi to do the repetitive work for building up an http request.

Here it is:

```
private callApi(method: string, route: string, options?: object, body?: object) {

// build up query parameters
let params = new HttpParams();
if (options) {
  _.forOwn(options, (val, key) => {
    params.append(key, val);
  })
}

// get and delete don't have a body
if (method == 'get' || method === 'delete') {
  return this.http[method](this.apiurl + route, {
    params: params,
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.GetToken())
  })
} else {
  return this.http[method](this.apiurl + route, body, {
    params: params,
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.GetToken())
  })
}
}
```

I'd like to call it with another method, for example:

```
ListCategories: (options?: object) => {
  return this.callApi('get', '/me/categories', options)
},
```

But I'd also like to somehow have it call that method with an interface specific to the method calling it.

So for example when I call ListCategories I would expect this generic method callApi to somehow be aware of the interface specific to listing categories. How might I accomplish this? I've tried passing the interface, but as I'm reading about interfaces it doesn't look like they exist during run time.

Comment: use a generic type `<T>`

Comment: But I would like a specific interface. I updated the method that calls it to: ListCategories: (options?: object): Observable<OcCategoryList> which seems to do what I want it to. So basically the method calling it has the interface defined, callApi doesn't. I think that's ok. maybe not best practices though?

Comment: *as I'm reading about interfaces it doesn't look like they exist during run time* - they surely don't. You possibly have XY problem. Consider providing detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve. What are those interfaces and how exactly callApi should be affected by them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking things like interceptors. If that is the case you can use angular interceptor.

- [angular 5 Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)
- [angular 5 Interceptor, blog](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Else look for the below-given soln using http.request method.

```
export class CustomHttpService {
  private apiurl: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    // test
  }
  public callApi<T>(method: string, route: string, options?: object, body?: object): Observable<T> {
    const params = new HttpParams ();
    if (options) {
      _.forOwn (options, (val, key) => {
        params.append (key, val);
      });
    }
    const headers = new Headers ();
    headers.set ('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.getTaken ())
    return this.http.request (this.apiurl + route, {
      method,
      body,
      params,
      headers
    }).map ((response) => response.json ());
  }
  private getTaken() {
    return 'xxxx';
  }
}
```